# My PHP Article has errors

Tags: php, html, content-management-system

My problem is, that when is post a article on my CMS containing this kind of chars `" or '`

On my news it displays like this `This is John\'s first post!`

How do i fix it? Thank you !

Add.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('../includes/connection.php');
include_once('../includes/infos.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

        if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><b>Erreur</b> : Tous les champs sont requis!</div>';
        } else  {
            $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content, article_timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
            $query->bindValue(1, $title);
            $query->bindValue(2, $content);
            $query->bindValue(3, time());

            $valide = '<div class="alert alert-success">Le news a √©t√© ajout√©</div>';
            $query->execute();
        }
    }
include_once ('inc/header.php');    
?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that displays the said content?

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answers but Jeffrey Carandang already helped me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use php stripslashes function.

here is the link : http://www.php.net/stripslashes